# How to replace the text on <td> in a <table> - using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I have a `<table>` with a `<td>` where I would like to replace the text - using javascript.

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="53ffaf3e436872c452020000">
        2014-08-16T11:00:00.000+02:00
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I receive from the server a `new_dates` object of `key`/`value` pairs that I loop through:

Coffeescript version:

```
last_dates.map (last_date) ->
  for key of last_date
    console.log key + " has the date: " + last_date[key] # 53ffb262436872c499b90f00 has the date: 2014-08-16T11:00:55.000+02:00
    $("##{key}").text = "#{last_date[key]}"
```

Javascript version:

```
last_dates.map(function(last_date) {
  var key, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (key in last_date) {
    console.log(key + " has the date: " + last_date[key]); // 53ffb262436872c499b90f00 has the date: 2014-08-16T11:00:55.000+02:00
    _results.push($("#" + key).text = "" + last_date[key]);
  }
  return _results;
});
```

The above code is supposed to find all the id's from `key`'s, and replace their text values with `value`'s. My code, however, does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery.text` is a function. You're trying to use it as a property. Try this instead:

```
$("#" + key).text(last_date[key]);
```

You don't need to prepend an empty String - anything you insert as a text node will be converted into a String.